# SwingWorker: Syntax error on token "execute" -?

Tags: java, swingworker

I'm trying to use a SwingWorker but for some reason at `worker.execute();` I receive the following error:

> "Syntax error on token "execute", Identifier expected after this
>   token"

That doesn't help much, it's a generic error, and no matter how stupid it might be, it's been torturing me for hours.. I've seen that moving SwingWorker somewhere else outside the class may fix it, but I don't understand how and why and why it should not work like this! Ugh!

```
public class App {

    private App() {  // CONSTRUCTOR

        final int WINHSIZE = 2000;
        final int WINVSIZE = 2000;

        class Enjoy extends JPanel  {

            @Override
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                g.drawLine(0, 0, 2000, 2000);
            }

            class MyExecutor extends SwingWorker<Void,Void> { 

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() {
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void done(){ // runs on EDT

                }
            }

            MyExecutor worker = new MyExecutor();
            worker.execute(); // What the hell is going wrong here?

        }

        Runnable runner = new Runnable() { 
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Title");
                JPanel panel = new Enjoy();
                JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
                f.add("Center", myScrollPane);
                f.pack();
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        };

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(runner);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new App();
    } 
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`worker.execute();` must be inside some method, it can't be directly within the scope of your `Enjoy` class.

Comment: Why??? is this a specific case or what? Is this wrong Java syntax in general? As I said in question, I'd like to know the reason behind it...

Comment: `it can't be directly within the scope of your Enjoy class.` for what reason exactly?

Comment: @jj_ This is wrong Java syntax in general. Statements must be inside a method, constructor or initializer block.

Comment: so basically you can't call functions form inside a class and outside a method, in Java ?

Comment: @jj_ The only exception to that rule is when you call the methods as an initialization of a class member. So `private int foo = bar();` can appear inside a class and outside a method, but `bar()` can't.

Comment: Thanks. I understand. About that, while trying stuff at some point I did: `something  = worker.execute();` At that point Eclipse stops marking it as an error and instead it marks as error the line just before it, on the `;` and the error becomes: `Syntax error on token ";", , expected`. How is this explained?

Comment: @jj_ In that case the compiler assumes you wanted to declare multiple members of the same type. While `String s = "something"; b = s.substring(3);` is invalid, `String s = "something", b = s.substring(3);` is valid - since it declares two String members.

Comment: One more thought, since we're here: would it be a bad idea in my case to put the SwingWorker .execute() method in the SwingWorker constructor, like so `public MyExecutor(){ this.execute();  }` ? Makes sense?